# How to check what authentication method a website is using

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use Python to log into some websites. Here is my sample code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
username='username' 
password ='alllongpasswordsareforchumps'
response = requests.get('https://github.com/', auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username,password))
print('Response Code '+ str(response.status_code))
```

I get `Response Code 200`, it should have been rejected. Even though the username and password mentioned here are not real. How can I check to see which authentication method the website is using?

Comment: GitHub's main page doesn't use the `Authentication` header (the value set with `auth = HTTPBasicAuth(...)`) at all, it uses cookies to verify if the user is logged in or not. You might want to look at the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) instead, which (I believe) uses Basic auth (but with a token instead of a password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unauthorized response you should send your request to other endpoints of Github instead of its base address for example see the below code snippet:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Making a get request to this address
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user',
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))

print(response)
# this will print: <Response [401]>
```

Make the request without attempting authentication, receive a *401* response, but github response doesn't have the `WWW-Authenticate` header for you to check the authentication method of this *RESTAPI* and for check github authentication ways, you should read [Basics of authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/basics-of-authentication) section on github docs.